# Why I am only getting the last value from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my Database file
    package org.easysolution.easydigitalsignage.activities;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class DATABASEVERSION4 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATABASEVERSION4";

public static final String TABLE_TWOO = "TABLE_TWOO";

//TABLE TWO CONSTRAINTS
public static final String S_ID="sid";
public static final String Sr1 = "Sr1";
public static final String Sr1mediatype="Mediatype";
public static final String Sr1Path = "Path";
public static final String Sr1Align = "Alligh";
public static final String Sr1Stretch = "Strech";
public static final String Sr1Duration = "Duration";
public static final String Sr1Height = "Height";
public static final String Sr1Width = "Width";
public static final String Sr1TotalHeight = "THeiht";
public static final String Sr1TotalWidth = "TWidth";
public static final String Sr1HeightPercent = "Heightper";
public static final String Sr1WidthPercent = "Widthper";

public static final String CREATE_TABLETWO = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TWOO + " ( " + S_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Sr1 + " TEXT , " + Sr1mediatype + " TEXT, " + Sr1Path + " TEXT, " + Sr1Align + " TEXT, " + Sr1Stretch + " TEXT, " + Sr1Duration + " TEXT, " + Sr1Height + " REAL, " + Sr1Width + " REAL, " + Sr1TotalHeight + " REAL, " + Sr1TotalWidth + " REAL, " + Sr1HeightPercent + " REAL, " + Sr1WidthPercent + " REAL )";

public DATABASEVERSION4(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLEONE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLETWO);


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TWOO);

}


public String Srn() {
    String Srnot = null;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT Sr1 FROM TABLE_TWOO";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        {
            do {
                Srnot = cursor.getString(0);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


    }

    return Srnot;

}



public Double Height(){
    Double HeighT=null;
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectquery= "SELECT Height FROM TABLE_TWOO";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectquery,null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        {
            do {
                HeighT=cursor.getDouble(0);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

public String Widthpe() {
    String WidthperT = null;
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT Widthper FROM TABLE_TWOO";
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        {
            do {
                WidthperT = cursor.getString(0);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


    }

    return WidthperT;

}
```

}

This is my Main Activity Class

```
   public void gettable_two(){
    tableOprations.openDatabase();

  //  getdbsNo=info.Srn();
    getdbmediaType=info.Mediatyp();
    getdbimagePath=info.Pat();
    getdballign=info.Allig();
    getdbscale=info.Strec();
  //  getdbsduration=info.Duratio();
   // getdbshght=info.Heigh();
    getdheight=info.Height();
    getdbswdth=info.Widt();
    getdbstotalHeight=info.THeih();
    getdbstotalWidth=info.TWidt();
    getdbsheightPercent=info.Heightpe();
    getdbswidthPercent=info.Widthpe();

    Log.i("kr", String.valueOf(getdheight));
    Log.i("krr", String.valueOf(getdballign));


}

public void getarraylistvalue(){




//Retrireving Array Start
    getsNoArray.add(getdbsNo);
    getmediaTypeArray.add(getdbmediaType);
    getimagePathArray.add(getdbimagePath);
    getalignArray.add(getdballign);
    getscaleTypeArray.add(getdbscale);
 //   getdurationArray.add(gedduration);
    gethghtArray.add(getdheight);
    getwdthArray.add(getdwidth);
    gettotalHeightArray.add(getdtotalheight);
    gettotalWidthArray.add(getdtotalwidth);
    getperHeightArray.add(getdheightper);
    getperWidthArray.add(getidthper);

   }
```

This is my database 
    [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixW3v.png)

I am fetching the data from jason and storing it into sqlite and then use it to dislpay the records when there is no internet

Some how i am able to store the data correctly in sqlite but when i retrive the data into an Array List i am getting only the last value

Comment: Make a method in Database file which returns you the list of your Model class. Do that using cursors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Just follow these steps. I have used this for my application. So just correlate with correct Columns and models in your application:-

```
public List<NotesModel> getListOfNotes() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NOTES + " ORDER BY DATETIME(" + CREATION_DATE + ") DESC;", null);
    return cursorToNotesList(res, db);


}
```

cursorToNotesList method:-

```
private List<NotesModel> cursorToNotesList(Cursor c, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    List<NotesModel> notesList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                NotesModel notesModel = new NotesModel();
                notesModel.setId(c.getInt(0));
                notesModel.setTimeOfNoteCreation(c.getString(1));
                notesModel.setNote(c.getString(2));
                notesModel.setBackgroundColor(c.getInt(3));
                notesModel.setTextColor(c.getInt(4));
                notesModel.setTitle(c.getString(5));
                notesModel.setPassword(c.getString(6));
                notesModel.setNoteIdentifier(c.getString(7));
                notesModel.setPauseText(c.getString(8));
                notesModel.setUniqueNoteId(c.getString(9));
                notesList.add(notesModel);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return notesList;
}
```

Additionally you can close the cursor in finally block.